# Lagrange Multiplier Question regarding boundaries

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The problem I'm looking asks us to find the absolute max and min of $f(x,y)$, which is $-x + 2y - 3z$. The constraint given is $x^2+2y^2+3z^2\le \frac{3}{2}$.

Because the constraint has an inequality, this means we are considering the boundary of the constraint, right? IIRC, the gradient of f (expressed as $\nabla f$) should equal 0...but $\nabla f$ is $<-1,2,-3>$...what does imply for the absolute max and min? (I found the max and min values given the constraint $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=\frac{3}{2}$, not sure if that is applicable to this situation).

Comment: What is IIRC? And why must the gradient vanish on the boundary?

Comment: To find the max and min given that constraint, you need to find any critical points, which are candidates for interior extrema, and then search for extrema on the boundary. In this case there are no critical points, so the extrema must lie on the boundary. In this case they can indeed be found using Lagrange multipliers, since the boundary is just $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=3/2$.

Comment: IIRC means 'If I recall Correctly.' Thank you, that makes sense!